# MVC5 website gets corrupted evrey few hours, And need to get recycled to work

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a website running on windows server 2012 R2
Its a MVC5 website already running for years
for the past few month evrey few hours+ (sometimes could be few days - in a good case),
some pages from website stops working
and i get an error 
**`External component has thrown an exception.`**

Here is the log from event viewer

```
Faulting application name: vbc.exe, version: 14.7.2558.0, time stamp: 0x59d41ad3
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18895, time stamp: 0x5a4b1b67
Exception code: 0xc0000142
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ecf30
Faulting process id: 0x26bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3a2cb9fe40011
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\vbc.exe
Faulting module path: KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: dd9550b4-0ebe-11e8-80e9-00155d018d08
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The only way to get the website running again in to recycle the application pool.
(just restarting the website wont help).

The issue is that it takes for the website 20-40 seconds to get back up and running after a recycle, And to do this few times in-middle of the day is not an option.

Here is some more error details:

- Sometime is see in the logs `csc.exe`  instead of `vbc.exe` [c sharp compiler vs visual basic compiler] (its a c# project but i use RDLC files, to render som reports, that is using the vb compiler)
- Its happening very random sometimes after few hours and sometimes after few days, but in most cases its like after 6 hours.

Here is what i already tried:

- Moved the website to another windows 2012 R2 server.
- Deleted the "ASP.NET temporary folder path" at "`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root`"
- Updated all windows updates & restarted the server.
- Followed all steps mentioned here [RDLC Native Error 255](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357624/rdlc-native-error-255)
- Uninstalled windows updates 3098779 and 3097997.
- Gave full permission for app pool/ user to the temp folders.
- Many more things i don't event remember.

**So far i'm still at page 1 with this issue. any ideas?**

UPDATE:
I added more logs now im getting the following:

```
 at Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport.EnsureExecutionSession()

    An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘255’.
```

And some other pages just throw `External component has thrown an exception.`

i have a strong feeling its related to that issue here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3118750/known-issue-for-security-updates-3098779-and-3097997-for-the-net-frame,
BUT i followed all the steps restarted few times and windows updates are up to date.

Comment: this is not much to go on.   Are there any errors being thrown in the website around the time the app pool gets corrupt other than KERNALBASE.dll one?  Why does the web site take so long to start?

Comment: why are `Faulting package full name:` and  `Faulting package-relative application ID:` empty ?

Comment: i wish i would know, why the names are empty. that's the issue i get no details just some very strange error code.

Comment: Ken Tucker: its takes long to start because it loads some modules that it out of our control, and NO other then this there is no other errors at all.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your application pool is crashing.

Check "System" logs in the Event Viewer for the same time stamp when you see this log in the "Application" logs. If you observe one of the following errors, then your application is definitely crashing.

- A process serving application pool '%1' suffered a fatal
  communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
  process id was '%2'. The data field contains the error number.
- A process serving application pool '%1' terminated unexpectedly. The 
  process id was '%2'. The process exit code was '%3'.

To understand more as to why the application is crashing, follow my blog here to capture a crash dump - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/parvez/2016/08/06/iis-application-pool-crash-and-debug-diag/

Comment: the thing is that most website pages still work, its only affecting some pages (and not the same page every time)

Comment: It could very well be a page that is causing the application pool to go down. Remember, your entire application is running inside the app domain of the application pool. So, even if one page goes down, entire application will go down. I would still recommend you to follow the steps mentioned above and share more details on system logs in event viewer.

Comment: thanks i will try it, but its not really crashing the whole pool most pages will work just fine.