# Reporting Services Deploy error: An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘255’

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019

I've installed Visual Studio 2019 and I've a project containing some Reporting Services Reports.
If I try to deploy one of these I receive following error:

**An unexpected error occurred while compiling expressions. Native compiler return value: ‘255’**

With previous Visual Studio 2017 version, all report deploy operations were ok.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VS 2015 Native compiler return value -1073741511 on .rdlc files when building project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766585/vs-2015-native-compiler-return-value-1073741511-on-rdlc-files-when-building-pr)

Comment: Looks like you might need to look at the solution on this other question ^.  Seems like its going to be an issue with the .NET version and installation. [Here's another question with some solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34357624/10755978).

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for your suggestions but the Framework updates mentioned into your links are not installed neither on my development notebook (where Visual Studio 2019 is installed) nor on the server (where SSRS server is installed).

I tried to create a simple report (without datasources) and deploy was ok.
Can the problem be related to datasources?

Comment: I solved my problem restarting Reporting Services service on server machine. I don't know why but this, actually, solved my issue